Sanding orange peel walls
I'm a complete beginner with home improvement and I'm not sure what to do with the orange peel walls of a room I'm renovating. So far I spackled in all the holes on every wall, and then sanded one wall manually, got exhausted, and just sanded (180 grit) over the spackle. I primed it to see how it'd look and it looks decent, but still very bumpy with a noticeable extruding "crack" in the wall. Should I just keep priming? Sand more? And for the other walls, should I just make sure the spackle is flush with the wall instead of sanding the whole wall? I'm also not sure how to deal with water damage under paint around windows.

Is the goal smooth walls?  Sanding orange-peel will result in "patchy" walls.  State your goal to get a proper answer.

Consider wallpaper.

You have multiple questions here. To answer not particularly in order.
1- Water stains need to be treated so they do not "bleed" through new paint. Apply a primer/sealer like Kilz to seal the area.
2- the crack in the wall should have any loose material removed. If the crack is bulging, the bulge needs to be removed. Sometimes it is easier to cut out the area that is proud of the wall surface with a razor knife and fill the area to make it flat. If the resulting area is 1/2 wide or so, just fill with patching compound. If it is much larger in width, some mesh drywall tape can be used to help strengthen the patch.
3-General hole filling and smoothing.  Small hole can be filled with spackling or drywall compound. Use a drywall taping knife that is at least 1 inch wider than the patch you are filling. When dry, I prefer to wipe the area with a damp drywall sponge rather than sand.  Sanding is good for removing ridges. Wiping with a sponge will smooth edges of a patch better with no dust.
4- Smoothing or texturing. If the goal is a smooth wall, you are better served by skimming a layer of drywall compound over the entire wall. Sanding any ridges when dry and then wiping the entire wall with a damp sponge to remove drywall dust. Prime and paint.
If you are good with an orange-peal texture, finish the patches as directed in step 3. Then spray orange-peal texture over the repair, extending the texture out about twice the size of the repair. This is more of an art than a science. You need to experiment with the spray pattern and distance from the wall to get a fair match. ( 2-3 feet from the wall and spraying in a moving circular motion works well for me.)  If there are many repairs, plan on spraying the entire wall.  When dry you can prime and paint. No need to wipe anything down.

Thank you for this! To clarify I want the walls to be as smooth as I can get them. I'll try to remove that extruding crack, but I don't know if I have enough resources to put compound over the whole wall. I might just have to live with orange peel.
